# Enabling Ant Tools in a new Eclipse Galileo installation

Tags: actionscript-3, eclipse, ant, build, build-automation

I have recently installed Eclipse Galileo with the PHP Developers Tools. I plan to install the Flash Builder 4 Plug-in to do ActionScript development as well.

I want to use Eclipse to both create an ant build script and execute it to compile ActionScript docs from an ActionScript 3 code library.

The problem is that when I try to run a build.xml file (which every site that answers the ant build questions says it should handle automatically) I never see an option to run it as an Ant Build, not can I find any way to associate XML files to Ant in the Preferences or External Tools dialogs.

I;ve seen numerous tutorials on build Ant build files, but never anything about running the actual build script.

Comment: Ivan solved the problem. I needed the JDT. I've also detailed setting up the Eclipse > Ant > AsDoc process in a blog post: http://foxr.aeoliandigital.com/archives/260

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install "Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools" component. It's in "Web, XML, and Java EE Development" of "Galileo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo" repository.